# isolating wired network

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have spent half a day with research, trial and error, before asking.

Two laptops, both running 16.04.
Laptop #1 has wifi Internet from Router #1.
Laptop #1 has Ethernet to Router #2

Laptop #2 has no wifi.
Laptop #2 has Ethernet to Router #2

I need to use samba/cfis from Laptop #2 to Laptop #1 - all good.

But, laptop #1 needs to be disconnected form the Ethernet to use the wifi for Internet. It seems that wire takes precedence over wireless.

Found some things to try.
Set Wired IPv4/DNS connections to "Link-Local-Only" but that breaks the samba/cfs.
Set Wired IPv4/DNS connections to "Shared-to-other-computers" but that breaks the samba/cfs.

1:
How do I have laptop #2 never seeing the Internet, but always seeing laptop number #1 via Ethernet?

2:
How do I have laptop #1 always connected to the Ethernet and thus , #2, but able to use the wifi Internet?

3:
Is there some way to set a Metric where the wifi is first in line for website use?
Thanks

Comment: You set your preferred internet device with route - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/route-examples/ . You can use ufw/iptables on the other laptop to drop all connections other then to your LAN.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thanks, routing changes have not helped. Research suggests it is a function of **systemd** as I cannot change anything.  **wlan0** and **eth0** are no longer used, It just reverts back to the automatic settings. I tried changing the metric using `ifmetric`but that too is ignored. It seems systemd documentation is not up to date.

Comment: If you need help with systemd use the Arch, Fedora, or other documentation - http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-docs.html . If you need assistance you need to provide details of what you tried, otherwise is sounds as if you do not understand how your interfaces are named or how to use route. Either provide details or RTFM.

Comment: You are asking more then one question and it is best to ask one question per question. We need details regarding your network , otherwise all we can say is use iptabels on "laptop #1" and route on "laptop #2".

Comment: OK  sorry I asked. RTFM? Really? What do you think the term "research" meant? I emulated everything suggested for the routing etc. It's a mess as it seems impossible to change the Metric. I after a lot of **research** it seems like just changing the Metric for the eth0 would solve this, but try as I might, nothing is changing the metric from 1.

Comment: Please don't rant at me. If you need help you need to provide more information, end of story. Start with one problem, say laptop #1 and limiting access. Post the output of ifconfig and information on your LAN ip address and I will write an iptables rule for you. If you don't post the information then read man iptables is the best I can offer. Same with laptop 2 and your route problem. Post ifconfig and route commands or read man route. Same with systemd. What problem do you have with systemd ? See also https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: Laptop #1, Laptop #2, Router#1, Router #2 , etc has no meaning. Car #1 in City #1 on highway #1 has to go to car #2 in city #2 on highway #2. Which way  do I turn ?